# How to find a meeting is a recurrence meeting or not in outlook using Apple script

Tags: macos, outlook, applescript

I need to identify a meeting created is a recurrence meeting or not using Apple script on outlook.

Do we have a way to do that.?

Thanks,
Ravi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears a calendar event is a recurrence if the value of `recurrence` is set i.e, NOT `missing value`

```
tell application "Microsoft Outlook"

    set hasRecurrence to the recurrence of calendar event 2 is not missing value

end tell
```

Comment: Thanks !!!  It worked but when i open the meeting invite directly then its not able to get the recurrence value